# TCP communication between python and raspberry pi and sending data and files

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, client, server

I am currently working on a program of mine to try to send two csv files from my raspberry pi (client) to my laptop (server). In addition, I need to write two different sets of data to the two different csv files. The first one is raw data which will continue to write in data every 30 seconds and another is averaging of the raw data every 15 mins)

My first question is: Is it possible to do the above task? Or do I need to write two different servers and clients codes? (Refer to both codes below). Can I combine both of them? So that it can write two different data (raw and averaging) to two different csv file at the same time.

My second question is: How do I append new sets of data without rewriting the entire file (I tried append before and it duplicates the file data over and over again).

Client.py (This code currently only sends one csv file which is the raw data)

```
  import time
  import socket

  TCP_IP = '192.168.1.105'
  TCP_PORT = 5005

  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
  f = open('sensingdata.csv', 'rb')
  print 'Sending...'
  l = f.read(1024)
  while (l):
      print 'Sending...'
      s.send(l)
      l = f.read(1024)
  print "Done Sending"
  time.sleep(30)
```

Server.py

```
  import socket
  import sys

  TCP_IP = ""
  TCP_PORT = 5005

  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
  s.listen(5)

  while True:
      conn, addr = s.accept()
      f = open('sensing1.csv', 'wb')
      print "Got connection from", addr
      print "Receiving..."
      l = conn.recv(1024)
      while (l):
          print "Receiving Data..."
          f.write(l)
          l = conn.recv(1024)
          print "Done Receiving"
      f.close()
      conn.close()
```

Client2.py (This code is for the appending of averaging data)

```
  import time
  import socket

  TCP_IP = '192.168.1.105'
  TCP_PORT = 5005

  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
  g = open('average.csv', 'rb')
  print 'Sending Averaging Data...'
  l = f.read(1024)
  while (l):
      print 'Sending...'
      s.send(l)
      l = g.read(1024)
  print "Done Sending"
  time.sleep(900)
```

Server2.py

```
  import socket
  import sys
  import csv

  TCP_IP = ""
  TCP_PORT = 5005

  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
  s.listen(5)

  while True:
      conn, addr = s.accept()
      g = open('average.csv', 'ab')
      print "Got connection from", addr
      print "Receiving Averaging Data..."
      l = conn.recv(1024)
      for rows in g:
      while (l):
          if row not in rows:
          print "Receiving Averaging Data..."
          g.write(l)
          l = conn.recv(1024)
          print "Done Receiving"
      g.close()
      conn.close()
```

Comment: `In addition, I need to write two different sets of data to the two different csv files. The first one is raw data `. Sorry but i do not understand a word of this. Lets assume you have a csv file. Then you write -raw- data to it. Then how would the file be changed? How would it look like?

Comment: I reread your post. It seems as if you only want to append some lines to an existing file. If so then why al this talking? And what is the difference between data and raw data?

Comment: I have 2 types of data, 1 is the normal data and another one will be run through another python code averaging.py to get the averaging of the normal data. Both will be write into two different csv file

Comment: Well ok. So you have two csv files. What's the problem? You did not describe. If you can upload a csv file you can upload another. So start explaining your problem. And please react to the point to my remarks and questions. You did not do that.

Comment: `TCP communication between python and raspberry pi and sending data and files`. Your subject is not ok. You suggest communication betwee a language and a small computer. You mean something different of course. Communication between laptop and raspberry?